# Share a magnific-popup on facebook

Tags: javascript, ajax, facebook, share, magnific-popup

It's posible to share a **magnific popup**, who is called with ajax, to facebook? In my Magnific popup i have images and text. I want to share not only an image but the whole content.

P.S. this website, it's One page.

Comment: The you can either share the link to the page itself (will show the title, description and thumbnail set for that), and add the text as a _quote_; or you need to create an individual URL for each combination of title/description/thumbnail that you want to share.

Comment: this website, it's one page.

Comment: Doesn’t change anything ...